# Apply multiple function with args when grouping dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am trying to do a group_by on a dataframe using the count_values function. I want a first column with the count including the NA values, and a second one with the normalized count. I have achieved this by creating 2 grouped DF and by concatenating them. However, this method does not seem very clean and there is probably a more pythonic way to do this.

The dataframe :

```
    store   item
0   Store1  table
1   Store2  chair
2   Store3  chair
3   Store2  table
4   Store2  chair
5   Store3  table
6   Store1  chair
7   Store1  table
8   Store3  None
```

The working code :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('store')['item'].apply(pd.value_counts,normalize=True,dropna=False)).rename(columns={"item":"normcount"})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('store')['item'].apply(pd.value_counts,dropna=False)).rename(columns={"item":"count"})
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
print(df3)

                normcount   count
store           
Store1  table   0.666667    2
        chair   0.333333    1
Store2  chair   0.666667    2
        table   0.333333    1
Store3  chair   0.333333    1
        table   0.333333    1
         NaN    0.333333    1
```

The non-working code that seems more pythonic:

```
df.groupby(['store','item']).agg(count=('item',pd.value_counts),normcount=('item',pd.value_counts(normalize=True,dropna=False)))

df.groupby(['store','item']).agg(count=('item',pd.value_counts),normcount=('item',pd.Series.apply(pd.value_counts,normalize=True,dropna=False)))

df.groupby(['store','item']).agg(count=('item','value_counts'),normcount=('item','value_counts'))
```

I have tried many variations of the first 2 code snippets above, without success. I either get a syntax error, or a type error. The last one works, but I cannot pass any args, and therefore I do not get the result I want.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Thank you !

Comment: Could you try wrapping a call to `pd.value_counts` in a lambda function? `lambda x: pd.value_counts(x, normalize=True, dropna=False)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but is not working correctly. If I keep 'items' in groupby, then I get 1 for every count. If I remove 'items', then I get a list for every store that is the length of the number of items with the ith value being the count of the ith item in the store, and not the count item by item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) directly and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
s = df.value_counts()

out = pd.concat([
           s.rename('count'),
           s.div(s.groupby(level='store').transform('sum')).rename('normcount')],
          axis=1).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
              count  normcount
store  item                   
Store1 chair      1   0.333333
       table      2   0.666667
Store2 chair      2   0.666667
       table      1   0.333333
Store3 None       1   0.333333
       chair      1   0.333333
       table      1   0.333333
```

Alternatively:

```
out = pd.DataFrame({
  'count': df.value_counts(sort=False),
  'normcount': df.groupby('store').value_counts(normalize=True, sort=False)
})
```

Comment: I believe the alternative is the most pythonic way to go! Thank you !

Comment: @Guillaume-ds yes, but it computes the `value_counts` twice, the first one might be more efficient if you have a large input which aggregates into a much smaller Series ;)

Comment: A quick test on 10M rows with 6x6 stores/items gives `1.87 s ± 151 ms` for the first approach and `2.85 s ± 346 ms` for the second one. (`95.8 ms ± 1.25 ms` vs `194 ms ± 13.2 ms` for 1M rows)

Comment: Thank you for this insight, indeed it can make a diffenrece !